# How can i insert an array of objects in MongoDB using Golang and Official mongo Driver

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go

I'm trying to insert an array of objects and also push new objects into that same array.
The problems is that when i insert the array, i get an object inside an array inside the parent array, this is my code

I tried this

```
type MessageRecords struct {
   Sender primitive.ObjectID  `json:"sender"  bson:"sender"
   Message string `json:"message"   bson:"message"`
}

type Room struct {
   ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id"  bson:"_id"`
   Records []MessageRecords
}
```

and this is the code when i insert

```
mRecords := &MessageRecords{
Sender : "62a54s3a21sd65a43a21ascas" //dummy ObjectID
Message : "This is a dummy message",
}

var room Room
room.ID = primitive.NewObjectID()
room.Records = append(room.Records, mRecords) 

db.dummyDB.insertOne(ctx,room)
```

But i get this result

```
"records": [
    [
      {
        "sender": {
          "$oid": "62cb43f59059283041b80da9"
        },},
        "message": "second message"
      }
    ]
  ]
```

i get the object inside a an array and inside another array.
Hopefully anyone can help me, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out, what i did in the models section is this

```
type MessageRecords struct {
   Sender primitive.ObjectID  `json:"sender"  bson:"sender"
   Message string `json:"message"   bson:"message"`
}

type Room struct {
   ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id"  bson:"_id"`
   Records interface{}  `json:"records,omitempty" bson:"records,omitempty"
}
```

And when insert the document i do this instead

```
var room Room
room.ID = primitive.NewObjectID()

db.dummyDB.insertOne(ctx,room)
```

Now i don't append nothing
But when i want to add a message i do this

```
var payload MessageRecords 

err := json.NewDecoder(w).Decode(&payload)
if err != nil {
// do something
}

var load Room 

load.Records = payload

// here i just push the object into the interface that is converted as array
err := appendMessageInDB(load) 
if err != nil {
// do something
}
```

And this is the result i get

```
 "records": [
    {
      "sender": {
        "$oid": "ObjectID"
      },
      "message": "first message"
    },
    {
      "sender": {
        "$oid": "ObjectID"
      },
      "message": "second message"
    },
    {
      "sender": {
        "$oid": "objectID"
      },
      "message": "third message"
    }
  ]
```

Hopefully i help somebody that is running with this problem :)
if somebody wants the code of how to update the array of recors, let me know!!